# Seg fault after 2 scanf to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, printf, scanf

I am getting my head wrapped around pointers, and I get a segmentation fault on this code, for no apparent reason.
Basically this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%i", *(&a));
    printf("1st number is: %i\n", *a);
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *a, *b;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%i", *(&a));
    printf("Please enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%i", *(&b));
    printf("1st number is: %i\n", *a);
    printf("2nd number is: %i\n", *b);
}
```

Just why?

Comment: Pointer is address to the data. Where does the pointer points now? Does it points to right memory address?

Comment: First part of your code does not work. See https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b4f6f10ed7d4a1a

Comment: `valgrind` is an amazing tool that you can run your program under. Literally just `valgrind ./a.out` and it will often tell you the simple mistakes you've made like this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared two pointers to integers, without ever declaring or allocating any memory that those pointers could point to. Rather, declare two integers on the stack, and pass pointers to them:

```
int a, b;
scanf("%i", &a);
scanf("%i", &b);
printf("Numbers: %i %i\n", a, b);
```

The fact that your first example works is out of pure luck--it's very likely that a seemingly-valid pointer was left on the stack at just the right location for the example to barely work.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them should work. If they work it's because *undefined behavior* includes the behavior of working properly.

Your main problem is that you are writing to an uninitialized pointer. I don't see why you want to use pointers here. If you want to, you have to make them point to something. This is one way:

```
int x;
int *a = &x; // Pointer that points to x
```

Or you could just remove the pointers completely:

```
int a;
printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("1st number is: %i\n", a);
```

And doing `*(&a)` is just unnecessary. It means exactly the same as `a`.